# What is utun0 and utun1 in network interfaces?

Tags: networking

I run the command `ifconfig` on my Mac, and I get a long list of network interfaces. At the bottom are 2 peculiar interfaces, `utun0` and `utun1`:

```
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::9bf4:4abb:9ca9:9b76%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::23e7:664c:8370:db7d%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

I do not know what these are. A quick search found an [old StackExchange post](https://superuser.com/questions/914685/what-is-creating-the-utun0-network-interface-on-osx-what-is-for-what-is-it-exa) that says it is for "Back to My Mac" feature. However, this feature was [discontinued this summer of 2019](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208922) according to Apple. Therefore, what is this? Why does it exist?

Answer (score 4):

These interfaces are used for VPN connections, regardless of whether VPN is enabled. See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310220/who-creates-utun0-adapter